# Could not load the assembly. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I looked into all the articles and solutions (most of them coming from this site or the ASP.NET forums archives, and could not find a solution to my situation.

Basically, I have a project for which the master pages depend on another (compiled, .dll) project of Master pages. I installed it fine on my machine, and it runs fine, but when we did the same thing on a colleague's machine, it always gives us that 500 Server Error:

> Could not load the assembly 'NAME_OF_ASSEMBLY'*. Make sure that it is
>   compiled before accessing the page.

An interesting point: it does not say "Could not load the assembly" with a name followed by and underscore and random letters, it just mentions the whole, proper name of the assembly.

Also weird point: The master pages (in the dependant project) all use some .dll files of compiled code. They have master pages that have no codebehind files, but do have the reference for the .dll included in that project. We tried copying all of those same files over, but to no avail.

We're simply at a point where we no longer know where to look or what to do. We reinstalled countless times, copied over my files, re-registered IIS, still nothing. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: The files you are installing on your colleague's machine are the same that work on your machine? Did you check the IIS features installed on your colleague's machine? Are the same that in yours?

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx Back to basics.

Comment: @EnriqueGonzález Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, we did a side-by-side comparison of IIS and the folder permissions of both solutions, to make sure they were identical and IIS_USRS were also added at the same places.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you so much, will have a read and try it immediately!

Comment: Hey @LexLi, we managed to get it running after more troubleshooting permitted thanks to the tool you suggested. Want to make it into an answer that I could accept? I'm sure it could help many more people in the future.
And, of course, a biiiiig thank you! :)

Comment: @Locutux feel free to post your own answer and accept it.